# I need to enable java (tm) plugin which installs applet in the browser.. How is it possible in Web Driver

Tags: java, applet, webdriver

I need to enable java (tm) plugin which installs applet in the browser.. How is it possible in Web Driver? 
I am testing a web app where some functionality has to be verified by enabling java(i.e., by installing applet) and also some functionality by disabling it. If applet works fine, then I need some expected results and if applet is not installed, I need some other results.. so how do i enable/disable applets(i.e.,java tm plugin) before launching browser..??
Please Help..

Currently am using WebDriver...

Comment: I hope it is an ActiveX window. check this [link](http://code.google.com/p/autoitx4java/). you can integrate AutoIt script within your java webdriver code and handle such window based GUIs

Comment: @HemChe : It is not an activeXwindow. When you launch Firefox , you can install java plugin to integrate with it, so that we can enjoy java applets supported by the browser. So we can also be able to disable it, so that it won't be supported. I need webdriver code to enable/disable that plugin(an extension to the browser).. Is it possible?? How??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a firefox profile to load firefox with the plugin which you want. Use the below code and replace the plugin name with your plugin name.

```
   File file = new File("firebug-1.8.1.xpi");
   FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
   firefoxProfile.addExtension(file);
   firefoxProfile.setPreference("extensions.firebug.currentVersion", "1.8.1"); // Avoid startup screen

   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
```

Source: [Click Here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver#Running_with_firebug)

Answer (score 0):

You can enable any Firefox plugin creating new profile and setting the preference.

For e.g. 
to enable java plugin

```
profile.setPreference("plugin.state.java", 2);
```

To enable flash plugin

```
profile.setPreference("plugin.state.flash", 2);
```

Sample code:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("plugin.state.java", 2);

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

I presume the "2" activates the plugin.